# How to create a LR(k) grammar for an arbitrary k

Tags: context-free, parsers, lr-k

Is there a simple procedure for constructing a grammar that is LR(k) but not LR(k-1) for any k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one pattern for an LR(k) grammar which is not LR(k-1).
I didn't fill in the definition of $A$; there's nothing particularly special about it. It might have an empty right-hand side, or it might match any LR(k) subgrammar. $a^k$ represents $k$ instances of $a$.

$$
\begin{align}S&\to B a^{k-1} b\\
S&\to C a^{k-1} c\\
B&\to A\\
C&\to A\\
A&\to \text{see above}
\end{align}
$$

Clearly, it is not possible to determine whether $A$ should be reduced to $B$ or to $C$ without knowing what the $k$ following token is. So the grammar is not LR(i) for any $i \lt k$. The reduction can be determined using $k$ lookahead tokens, so the grammar is LR(k) provided that $A$ is.